# How to stash properly on a rebased/reset upstream?

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a repo from the original base A, to current HEAD (stashed B). In the meanwhile, the remote upstream was updated from A to C. I would like to rebase my local to C and stash B on top of that:

```
Remote: A -> C ---
             ---^
             |
Local:  A -> B
```

What I did was:

```
git stash push                # Save my current HEAD B in stash
git fetch remote
git reset --hard remote/main  # This set my current HEAD to remote C
git stash pop                 # Merge B into C
```

However after stash popped, new changes from remote C is missing and deleted during the stash merge. How do I do this properly? Should I do a rebase instead of reset, regular pull, merge, pull rebase, cherry-pick the stash commit, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `git fetch`, you should use `git rebase remote/main` to replay your commits on top of the remote branch.

`git stash push / git stash pop` has only reapplied *the modifications you had on top of `B`*, not `B` itself.
`git reset --hard ...` has moved your branch to `C` without keeping any of the history specific to `B`.

---

From your current situation :

1. spot the `<sha>` of your commit `B` in your reflog, and create a branch on that :

```
git reflog main

# spot the sha for 'B', right before your 'reset to remote/main' action

git branch my-main B
```

2. stash your changes again, reapply B, then reapply your stash :

```
git stash
git cherry-pick B
git stash apply
```

3. if all has gone well (inspect the content of your repo), you can drop your latest stash and delete your branch `my-main`

```
git stash drop
git branch -D my-main
```